Bound for singular values in terms of traces: a 6th power inequality
In the recent paper of Guth and Maynard on large values of Dirichlet polynomials https://arxiv.org/html/2405.20552v1  there is a linear algebra lemma 4.2. Bound for singular values in terms of traces:
Let $A$ be a complex $n\times m$ matrix. Then there is a bound for the largest singular value as follows: $s_1(A)\leq 2\left(\mathrm{tr}((AA*)^3)-\frac{\mathrm{tr}(AA*)^3}{m^2}\right)^{1/6}+2 \left(\frac{\mathrm{tr}(AA*)}{m}\right)^{1/2}$.
They prove it from the folowwing inequality for non negative reals $x_1,\dots , x_k$:
$x_1\le 2\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^6-\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2)^3}{k^2}\Bigr)^{1/6}+2\Bigl(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}{k}\Bigr)^{1/2}.
$
Questions:
Q1: is there a literature on this last inequality? Is there a geometric interpretation?
Q2: Is its use on singular values indeed very new in linear algebra? If not, where could I read more?
(According to Tao this paper is a breakthrough in number theory, apologies for mentioning only a small step).

I would say that it's more a statistical result. In a sense, you are working with higher moments of random variables to obtain more precise bounds
